# What will be the answer to these 2 variables? and what are the differences between the both?

Tags: dart

double num1 = 0.0000012345.toStringAsPrecision(15);
double num2 = 0.0000012345.toStringAsFixed(15);

Answer (score 0):

First is first, you can't store a String object into a double variable, these two functions will return you a String object.

You should check on dart documentation, there you'll able to find out the answers for your question.

[toStringAsPrecission](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/num/toStringAsPrecision.html):

> Converts this to a double and returns a string representation with e**xactly precision** significant digits.
> The parameter precision must be an integer satisfying: **1 <= precision
> <= 21**.

[toStringAsFixed](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.10.4/dart-core/num/toStringAsFixed.html):

> Converts this to a double **before computing the string representation**.

> If the absolute value of this is **greater or equal to 10^21** then this methods returns an exponential representation computed by **this.toStringAsExponential()**. Otherwise the result is the closest string representation with exactly fractionDigits digits after the decimal point. If fractionDigits equals 0 then the decimal point is omitted.

> The parameter fractionDigits must be an integer satisfying: **0 <= fractionDigits <= 20**.